# Is Notes and Queries peer-reviewed?

Tags: peer-review, journals, journal-workflow

*[Notes and Queries](https://academic.oup.com/nq)* is a very famous and very long-running humanities journal, noted for its pioneering question-and-answer format.  It's spun off a number of regional editions, a series of anthologies, and given rise to countless imitators.

I'd like to know whether (and if so, which types of) contributions to *Notes and Queries* are peer-reviewed.  The journal's own website is silent on the matter—the only reference I can find to the review process is a short statement in the [guidance for contributors](https://academic.oup.com/nq/pages/General_Instructions) that professional editing can help non-native speakers of English "ensure that the academic content of [their] paper is fully understood by journal editors and *reviewers*" (emphasis mine—and note that this statement refers only to "reviewers", not "peer reviewers").  And third-party sources give conflicting or incomplete information on the journal's peer-reviewed status.  For example:

- The journal index of the [MLA International Bibliography](https://www.ebscohost.com/titleLists/mla-coverage.htm) lists *Notes and Queries* as peer-reviewed, but doesn't indicate whether this applies to all types of submissions.  (Maybe only the peer-reviewed submissions get indexed.)
- Various author-contributed reports on the [English Literature Journals](https://humanitiesjournals.fandom.com/wiki/English_Literature_Journals#Notes_and_Queries) page of the [Humanities Journals Wiki](https://humanitiesjournals.fandom.com/) mention a (sometimes lengthy) review process for submissions, but they never mention whether this is peer review or editorial review.
- [An informal but fairly lengthy review of *Notes and Queries*](https://forums.signumuniversity.org/index.php?threads/journal-highlights-notes-queries.2639/) by Richard Rohlin (then a graduate student at Signum University) states that the journal is not peer-reviewed.

So what's the story here?  *Notes and Queries* clearly has some sort of review process, but is it peer review?  And if so, which of its four types of contributions (Notes, Queries, Replies, and Reviews) are peer-reviewed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having just had a piece accepted for publication in the journal, albeit without having received copies or even mention of any reviews, I decided to ask the editorial assistant, Alicia Black, whether submissions to *Notes and Queries* undergo peer review.  This is her response in full:

> *N&Q* is a peer reviewed journal.  Your Query has been reviewed, though Queries do not always need a detailed review.

Answer (score 1):

*Notes and Queries* is listed in Web of Science's Arts & Humanities Citation Index (AHCI). This fact indicates that the journal's "primary research articles must be subject to external peer review" (according to [Web of Science's evaluation criteria](https://clarivate.com/webofsciencegroup/journal-evaluation-process-and-selection-criteria/)).

As Web of Science regularly evaluates its journals, one can probably trust that *Notes and Queries* indeed has a peer-review procedure, at least for its "primary research articles".

On the other hand, if you look at [Publons' page on *Notes and Queries*](https://publons.com/journal/17053/notes-and-queries), one cannot see any confirmed peer reviews yet (it says "< 10" [less than ten] reviews are confirmed, but that can be a range from zero to nine).